# Adjusting JDialog Size

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

I'm trying to make a `JDialog` with the size of the `JOptionPane` that contains, but function `getSize` is returning something a little bit smaller than the `JOptionPane` and the button of accept is not seen.

I'm trying this:

```
JOptionPane panel = new JOptionPane(orden);
JDialog informa = panel.createDialog("Orden"); 
//panel.validate();
informa.setSize(panel.getSize());
```

where `orden` is a `String` with the info I want to display.

I'm not trying a scroll bar because it will be horizontal scroll and its uncomfortable.

**EDIT:** If I try to reach the size with

```
informa.setSize(panel.getWidth(),panel.getHeight());
```

It happens exactly the same, it gets the right width but it gets a little bit less height, so I guess the getHeight is failing.

**MY SOLUTION:** Just adding 25 to getHeight

```
informa.setSize(panel.getWidth(),panel.getHeight()+25);
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure it includes the `setVisible` calls and the parent of the dialogs.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display, and what is the required functionality for the dialog?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [JOptionPane.showMessageDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29), or one of the 3 others, method??

Comment: I'm not using showMessageDialog because I need to add 3 buttons with different functions.
I'm displaying information from the selected row of a JTable, which contains data from database. And I need the buttons to fill an inform, to make an exportation file and to print another kind of inform.

Comment: MCVE is going to be a little bit complex here

Comment: Create your own JDialog using an appropriate layout manager(s) and don't use JOptionPane at all.  Use the JDialog pack method to make the JDialog the preferred size of your Swing components.

Comment: MCVE is not complex by definition.

Comment: And your solution is not robust.

Comment: WOW [@trashgod](http://stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod) IDFKW I didn't use it! I feel really ashamed now

Comment: SOMEONE TO CLOSE THIS QUESTION PLEASE

Comment: No shame; glad it helped; more on preferred size [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: Thank you, the worst is that I'm coding without using desing view and I have used pack for my messages dialogs